# How to use the ANTLR 4 TestRig to show which lexer rule is used when tokenizing input?

Tags: unit-testing, antlr, grammar, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I have an ANTLR 4 lexer grammar with a BEGIN lexer rule and an ID lexer rule:

```
lexer grammar Begin;                  

BEGIN : 'begin' ;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

After generating the lexer and compiling, I ran the ANTLR TestRig tool with input `'begin'`:

```
grun Begin tokens -tokens
begin
^Z
```

I got this output:

```
[@0,0:4='begin',<1>,1:0]
[@1,7:6='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

Notice the token type is 1 (as <1> indicates).

I ran it again, this time with input `'beginning'`:

```
grun Begin tokens -tokens
beginning
^Z
```

I got this output:

```
[@0,0:8='beginning',<1>,1:0]
[@1,11:10='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
```

Why do I get the same token type? Does that mean the lexer is using the same lexer rule for both inputs?

How do I get TestRig to show me that the lexer uses this rule: `BEGIN : 'begin' ;`

for tokenizing this input: `begin`

and this rule: `ID  : [a-z]+ ;`

for tokenizing this input: `beginning`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following test setup:

```
grammar Begin;

test: (BEGIN | ID)+;

BEGIN : 'begin' ;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

with ANTLRWorks 2.1. It works as expected:

with 'begin':

```
Arguments: [Begin, test, -tokens, -tree, -gui, C:\ANTLR\Begin.txt]
[@0,0:4='begin',<1>,1:0]
[@1,5:4='<EOF>',<-1>,1:5]
(test begin)
```

with 'beginning':

```
Arguments: [Begin, test, -tokens, -tree, -gui, C:\ANTLR\Begin.txt]
[@0,0:8='beginning',<2>,1:0]
[@1,9:8='<EOF>',<-1>,1:9]
(test beginning)
```